# How to auto-update apps managed by MDM?

Tags: ios, ios8, mdm, airwatch

I'm building an in-house app that is distributed via the AirWatch app catalog. The app always runs with Guided Access enabled and all devices running it are managed by AirWatch. My questions are regarding auto-update:

1. Is there a way that AirWatch can force the update immediately or as soon as the device comes back online, without asking for the user's input? If so, how does the app being open affect this behavior? How does guided access being enabled affect this behavior?
2. Is there a link from AirWatch, perhaps an `itms-services://` link, that the app can call to install the new version if a web service had indicated that it's no longer the latest version? If so, how does Guided Access being enabled affect this behavior?
3. Is there any other good model for remotely updating the app that will spread the update as quickly as possible and under the above conditions? The solution can be using MDM or a custom web service or both combined.

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your devices are running iOS7 and you have your app Deployment settings set to "Auto" (as opposed to "On-Demand") the device will automatically take the update once it processes the APNs notification to do so. If the device is locked/offline it will typically check for outstanding APNs messages within a minute or so of being unlocked or coming back online.

What I don't know is since your app is in guided access mode if you're receiving a pop-up to install the new version. I've seen previously where if the app that requires an update is open iOS will prompt. What we have done to battle this is embed a check in the app that phones home to see if the app is current. If the app is NOT current the user can't do anything until they update their app.

Regarding a direct-link to the App Catalog to update the app that might get tricky with guided access enabled. Before you even try to tackle that issue understand that the app catalog webclip URL contains the UDID of the device as of AW7.1 (I think). Since the UDID is no longer programmatically accessible code-side AirWatch allows you to push the UDID upon app installation in the Deployment/Application Configuration section. You can embed {DeviceUid} into the key share on the device which will make it accessible for that applciation, hence allowing you to create the appropriate App Store URL within your app.

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

honestly I didn't work with AirWatch. But I don't think that Apple provides a way for automatic update of ad-hoc or enterprise apps.

Well, I can describe a solution for an enterprise app I developed last year. Hope it will help you somehow.

First of all, I made it as a part of our secure website. (a little test flight)

Here's how app update works

- When the app launches it sends special request to a server asking if
  it is outdated and a new app version is available. (+ servers sends
  url for new version installation (with `itms-services://`))
- Then
  if update is required, app fires alert with description of new
  version, if user taps `update`, the app opens Safari where the user
  is able to install a new version.

We made to different kinds of alert, optional (minor version change) and compulsory(major version change). With later variant user is unable to get rid of alert view, so he has to update the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your internal app through the AirWatch Console and applications versioning.

I never used it but I imagine that at the end of the new version process, there is a way to push the updated app to the related devices. If the `Push Mode` is set to `Auto`, the user won't have to do anything and the app should be updated. If it is `On Demand`, the use will have to initiate the process from the `App Catalog`. From for the latest option, you have the solution to send a notification to the user.

It is also possible to retire or inactivate older versions to only keep the newest one.

If you have access to AirWatch Online Documentation, I recommend you the page `Using Add Version for Applications`. If you don't, contact your administrator and ask for all the pages located in `Mobile Application Management -> Internal Applications` and the page `Using Add Version for Applications`.

You should try it with a single device though ;)